# Problem in static initialization while running C++ executable in android?

Tags: c++, android, static, build, mips

Please find attached my test C++ code which i have put inside the Android Source/external/statictest folder. The files inside this folder are statictest.cpp, statictest.h and Android.mk.

---

**statictest.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "statictest.h"



NPT_Mutex Application::lock;

int main()
{
//    NPT_Mutex *obj = new NPT_Mutex();
//    Application *obj = new Application();
    printf("Lock address is 0x%x\n",(unsigned int)&(Application::lock));
    return 0;
}
```

---

**statictest.h**

```
class NPT_Mutex
{
    public:
        NPT_Mutex(){result = 10;}
        ~NPT_Mutex(){}

    private:
        int result;

};

class Application
{
    public:
        Application(){}
        ~Application(){}

        static NPT_Mutex lock;

};
```

---

**Android.mk**

```
ifneq ($(TARGET_SIMULATOR),true)

LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= statictest.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= statictest.h
LOCAL_MODULE := statictest
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libcutils libc libstdc++
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

endif  # TARGET_SIMULATOR != true
```

---

I have compiled the source code and created the executable using Android Build Setup with MIPS toolchain. But what i see is that the static initialization is not happening here. But the same code when it is run in the x-86 environment using the x-86 toolchain it is clearly getting initialized.

Please shed in your valuable pointers for me to understand this problem and solve it.

Thanks,
Sen

Comment: What does printf show? Can you print the value of result? Perhaps add some printf to constructor and destructor? Out of curiosity why would a mutex member of a class need to be static anyway?

Comment: Actually this is a test implementation, I was actually trying to port a project to Android, and it has a number of static members like this..

Comment: Have you dumped out what gets put in .init section by the linker ? use objdump to check
See if you can break with gdb/gdbserver in __do_global_ctors_aux and see if it steps through executing the global constructors at all.

I suspect this would be some MIPS bionic C lib / toolchain combination related issue. Where does your toolchain come from, MIPS supported Android fork at http://developer.mips.com/android/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You put your static instance in "`main.cpp`", so that seems like it should have worked (since there is no ambiguity about construction before "`main()`").

However, I've had similar problems of static instances across DLL boundaries, or when singletons reference other singletons (`A` could reference `B` after `B` was allocated, but before the `B::B()` constructor is called).  In such cases, a reasonable work-around (that *should* also work for you) explicitly forces instantiation:

```
//SomeClass my_singleton;   // OLD, NOW INSTANTIATE EXPLICITLY

SomeClass& GetSomeClassSingleton(void) {
  static SomeClass my_singleton;  // Instantiate once, explicitly
  return my_singleton;
}
```

In some cases, you may want to instantiate "somewhat dynamically":

```
SomeClass& GetSomeClassSingleton(void) {
  static SomeClass* my_singleton = NULL;
  if(!my_singleton) {
    my_singleton = new SomeClass();
  }
  return *my_singleton;
}
```

Of course, the approaches work fine even in the event you need to pass parameters to the constructor of your singleton.

Good luck, and let us know if you get that working on Android (I really want to know what works there).  I would guess that Android process-loading presents similar problems to singletons-across-DLL-boundaries, and I use the above patterns for singletons in such cases.